# White space counter

Tags: python

> Your program should ask the user to input the list, then it should call the function, and print the result. with the following condition:
>
> It returns True if the given list has at least 2 white spaces and False otherwise.

My code:

```
n = ((input("Please input a list of numbers separated by space:")))
t = 0
k = n.count(' ')
for i in range(0,len(n)):
    if n[i] > "   ":
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

print("There are",k,"space which has two length run")
```

My program counts all of the white spaces, but I want it to only count the 2 white spaces or more and return True or False otherwise

[image: Click here for the result of the image]

Comment: You might start with `print('4' > '  ')` and see what you get.

Comment: Why don't you print `repr(n[i])` along side your "True" or "False", so you can see whether its value matches what you expect (and can try comparing that value with your desired two spaces at the REPL, to tune your logic appropriately)?

Comment: `if n[i] > "   "` does not mean `if more than three spaces`. You also don't show the code that prints out the last line.

Comment: Also note, your teacher may not give you full marks unless you call a function, as per the instructions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What does "repr" do ?

Comment: @DanielleM. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Kishan, `repr()` prints a representation of your value -- so for a string with a space it'll print something like `' '`, including the quotes. The value is that it prints the variable in such a way that you can type that exact string into an interpreter to refer to it again (wherever possible).

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues with this code.

First, you do not define a *function* as stated in the requirements.

Second, `k = n.count(' ')` already counts all the spaces in the input string.  You do not need to loop over each character.

Third, even if you did need to loop over the characters, `n[i] > "   "` is definitely not the right way to do what you want.

Fourth, what is the purpose of the `t` variable?

Fifth, why is `input()` enclosed in two extra layers of parentheses?

Comment: Hey,
Thank you for answering my question
This is my first time with python
I didn't realize that "k.count(' ') was looping it for me.
So that clears some of the confusions I had

I want to know how do I proceed with it if i wasn't using k.count and i want to do the counting using the for loop (you said it's not the right way to do the way i did it, so how can i correct that ??)

The 't' variable was for the counting i was supposed to add (t += 1) for the counting but it seems when i ran it, it didn't make any difference if I put in the t+= 1 function or not.

Comment: Lastly 
I had 2 extra layer of parentheses because I was trying to do the code without using map as shown below

 s = list(map(float,input('Please input a list of numbers separated by space:').strip().split(' ')))

Comment: So how should I modify my code so that it works the way I want it to

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why you think you need a loop.

Try simply

```
print(n.count(' ') >= 2)
```

Or rather

```
def foo(n):
    return n.count(' ') >= 2

print(foo(input("Enter some numbers:")))
```

Comment: The question says "list" rather than "string", but I don't know what a list with white spaces would look like...

Comment: `input()` only returns strings

Comment: @KenY-N This is obviously a beginner-level assignment.  I can't imagine it would use any input method other than `input()`.

Comment: I like the way you have written the code.
I hadn't thought of that

Thank You so much for your help

Comment: @JohnGordon You commented " I can't imagine it would use any input method other than input()"  are there any other ways to input ?

Comment: I tested your code and there is one small problem with it
It counts the total number of spaces in the given entry
How to make it only count the number of spaces between consecutive numbers and if it is 2 or more it returns true and false otherwise

EG: it returns FALSE when the numbers are "2 4 5 6 7"

The code you have written returns True for the above situation

Comment: @Kishan Your question didn't say anything about if the spaces were consecutive, but you can literally count `'  '` (two spaces) instead

Comment: @cricket_007 What changes should be made to the code you wrote up there, to make it work in such a manner?

Comment: @Kishan I already said.. Replace `' '` (one space) with `'  '` (two spaces)... I would suggest you open a new question with example of the inputs that you think should return true or false because this answer does exactly what you need -- *True if the given list has at least 2 white spaces, else False*

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks and I will open a new question giving examples.